# Окружность вокруг div при наведении курсора

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, анимация

У меня есть div в форме солнца. Я просто хочу показать границу при наведении, с прозрачным промежутком между  объектом и границей.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сначала я пробовал `box shadow`, но не мог сделать белый пробел. Он требует сплошного цвета. Затем я попытался таким образом, как в коде ниже, но пробел не появляется.

Здесь мой код:

```css
    .sun-quote-pages{
      border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #f4953b;
        width: 4.1em;
        height: 4.1em;
        border: 2px solid transparent;
        transition: transform 0.5s ease, background 0.5s ease, box-shadow 0.5s ease;
    }
    
    .sun-quote-pages:hover {
         transform: scale(1.3);
        border: 2px solid #f4953b;
        margin: 2px;
        padding: 2px; 
    }
    
    
    .wrapper{
      margin-left:150px;
      margin-top:50px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="sun-quote-pages">   
      </div> 
    </div>
```

Что мне здесь не хватает?

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qsb6y0rc/4/)

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Circle around div when hover](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51258589/7394871) от участника  [@Janath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5774848/janath).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/51258589/7394871

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как вариант:

```css
.sun-quote-pages {
      border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #f4953b;
        width: 4.1em;
        height: 4.1em;
        transition: 0.5s all;
        position: relative;
    }

    .sun-quote-pages:hover {
         transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    
.sun-quote-pages:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top:0;
      bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 2px solid #f4953b;
      transition: 0.5s all;
}

.sun-quote-pages:hover:after {
      transform: scale(1.15);
}
    

    
    
    .wrapper{
      margin-left:150px;
      margin-top:50px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="sun-quote-pages">   
      </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: отдаю решение вам. Но на мой взгляд более сильное решение, у автора ответа с Enso на основе -  `background-clip: content-box;`

Answer (score 10):

Решением является `background-clip`, которое можно найти здесь:

https://css-tricks.com/transparent-borders-with-background-clip/

С его помощью вы можете помешать цвет фона под `border` и `padding`. Это свойство широко поддерживается:

https://caniuse.com/#search=background-clip

```css
.sun-quote-pages{
  border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #f4953b;
    width: 4.1em;
    height: 4.1em;
    padding: 2px; 
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    background-clip: content-box;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease, border 0.5s ease;
}

.sun-quote-pages:hover {
    border: 2px solid #f4953b;
    transform: scale(1.3);
}


.wrapper{
  margin-left:150px;
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sun-quote-pages">   
  </div> 
</div>
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/auzjv4rp/11)

*Или вариант с двойной границей:*

```css
.sun-quote-pages{
  border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #f4953b;
    width: 4.1em;
    height: 4.1em;
    padding: 2px; 
    border: 6px double transparent;
    background-clip: content-box;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease, border 0.5s ease;
}

.sun-quote-pages:hover {
    border: 6px double #f4953b;
    transform: scale(1.3);
}


.wrapper{
  margin-left:150px;
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sun-quote-pages">   
  </div> 
</div>
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/auzjv4rp/13)

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Circle around div when hover](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51258940/7394871) от участника  [@KIKO Software](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3986005/kiko-software).</sub>

Comment: Такое можно сделать и с `box-shadow`))

Comment: Смотрю щас все примеры с планшета - работают все реализации...только получается не ховер а клик

Answer (score 7):

```css
.sun-quote-pages {

    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #f4953b;
    width: 4.1em;
    height: 4.1em;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;

    transition: 0.5s;

}

.shadow {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;


}

.sun-quote-pages:hover {

    transform: scale(1.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px white, 0px 0px 0px 6px #f4953b;
}


.wrapper {
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="shadow">
  <div class="sun-quote-pages">   
  </div>
  </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Работает только на однотонном фоне.Минусами не кидайтесь - написал потому что мог.

Answer (score 2):

Вот еще CSS способ на градиенте =)

```js
let frames = Array(17).fill(0).map((e,i)=>`${i*6.25}%{--c2:hsla(30,100%,60%,${i/17})}`);
document.head.innerHTML += `<style>@keyframes circle {${frames.join('')}}</style>`
```

```css
sun {
  --c2: #f930;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, 
    #f93f, #f93f 50%, #f930 51%, #f930 54%, var(--c2) 56%, #f930 58%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  transition: 1s
}

sun:hover {
  animation: 0.5s circle forwards;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<sun></sun>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT да, но я им css создал :), при желании можно сразу готовый вставить, только листинг будет больше

Comment: @Alexandr_TT дело не в ней, просто увидел что можно так сделать, и проголосовать забыл